# How to read all nodes value with nodes name from XmlDocument

Tags: c#, json, xml, angular

I have below xml: -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tsResponse xmlns="abc.com/api" xmlns:xsi="www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="abc.com/api abc.com/api/ts-api-2.3.xsd">
    <pagination pageNumber="1" pageSize="100" totalAvailable="2" />
    <views>
        <view id="2adaf1b2" name=" Users by Function" contentUrl="ExampleWorkbook/sheets/UsersbyFunction">
            <workbook id="9fb2948d" />
            <owner id="c2abaaa9" />
            <usage totalViewCount="5388" />
        </view>
        <view id="09ecb39a" name=" Users by Site" contentUrl="ExampleWorkbook/sheets/UsersbySite">
            <workbook id="9fb2948d" />
            <owner id="c2abaaa9" />
            <usage totalViewCount="95" />
        </view>
    </views>
</tsResponse>
```

I want to display totalAvailable, view name, view id, view content url, totatviewcount in my angular 2 application.

I have converted my xml to json: -

```
{{
  "tsResponse": {
    "xmlns": "abc.com/api",
    "xsi": "www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "schemaLocation": "abc.com/api abc.com/api/ts-api-2.3.xsd",
    "_value": [
      {
        "pagination": {
          "pageNumber": "1",
          "pageSize": "1000",
          "totalAvailable": "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "views": {
          "_value": [
            {
              "view": {
                "id": "2adaf1b2",
                "name": " Users by Function",
                "contentUrl": "ExampleWorkbook/sheets/UsersbyFunction",
                "_value": [
                  {
                    "workbook": {
                      "id": "9fb2948d"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "owner": {
                      "id": "c2abaaa9"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "usage": {
                      "totalViewCount": "57"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "view": {
                "id": "09ecb39a",
                "name": " Users by Site",
                "contentUrl": "ExampleWorkbook/sheets/UsersbySite",
                "_value": [
                  {
                    "workbook": {
                      "id": "9fb2948d"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "owner": {
                      "id": "c2abaaa9"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "usage": {
                      "totalViewCount": "9"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}}
```

but its becoming more complex because every time xml will have different child nodes.
Please let me know if you have an idea about this scenario.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generated json will have a same structure always right. Or your xml itself is dynamic. Confused here.

Comment: @gusaindpk, xml is also dynamic for some parameter returns different child nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you want to try with [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source file helper to work with different file formats.

Here is how you can accomplish you needs

```
    static void Test()
    {
        int totalAvailable;
        using (var parser = new ChoXmlReader("sample9.xml", "abc.com/api").WithXPath("/tsResponse/pagination")
            .WithField("totalAvailable", fieldType: typeof(int))
        )
        {
            totalAvailable = parser.FirstOrDefault().totalAvailable;
        }

        using (var parser = new ChoXmlReader("sample9.xml", "abc.com/api").WithXPath("/tsResponse/views/view")
            .WithField("view_id", xPath: "@id")
            .WithField("view_name", xPath: "@name")
            .WithField("view_content_url", xPath: "@contentUrl")
            .WithField("view_total_count", xPath: "/x:usage/@totalViewCount", fieldType: typeof(int))
        )
        {
            using (var writer = new ChoJSONWriter("sample9.json")
                )
            {
                foreach (dynamic rec in parser)
                    writer.Write(new { view_id = rec.view_id, view_name = rec.view_name, view_content_url = rec.view_content_url, view_total_count = rec.view_total_count, view_total_available = totalAvailable });
                writer.Write(parser);
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
[
 {
  "view_id":"2adaf1b2",
  "view_name":"Users by Function",
  "view_content_url":"ExampleWorkbook/sheets/UsersbyFunction",
  "view_total_count":95,
  "view_total_available":2
 },
 {
  "view_id":"09ecb39a",
  "view_name":"Users by Site",
  "view_content_url":"ExampleWorkbook/sheets/UsersbySite",
  "view_total_count":95,
  "view_total_available":2
 }
]
```

Hope this helps.